# How do I conditionally add a clause to my query in PHP?

Tags: php

In my search form I have, value male, value female, and value both. If you select both, I do not wish to have at WHERE the "sex = '$sex'"

Should i do it like this:

```
if(empty($sex)){ // value empty if you chose "both"
$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE (firstname LIKE '%$firstname%' OR lastname LIKE '%$lastname%')";
}else{
$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE (firstname LIKE '%$firstname%' OR lastname LIKE '%$lastname%') AND sex = '$sex'";
}
```

Or is there a smart way to write this?

Comment: Interesting title. Consider using gender.

Comment: Empty sex is far more interesting.

Comment: HAHA! Now when I read the title again... That was funny :P I like using "sex" rather than gender.

Answer (score 6):

Do *never* build an SQL string from user input. That's what prepared statements are for. They are secure, perform faster when re-executed and they're easy to use, so use them:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT
    firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort
  FROM
    users 
  WHERE
    (firstname LIKE '%'|| ? || '%' OR lastname LIKE '%'|| ? || '%')
    AND Sex = CASE ? WHEN 'both' THEN Sex ELSE ? END
";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $lastname, $sex, $sex);

$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This is the correct and much more secure way of doing this. An even higher level approach is to use a class to encapsulate this, or use one of the dozens of ORM frameworks available out there. Like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108699/good-php-orm-library

Comment: @visionary: I'd say that this code above is the smallest common denominator. Shallow learning curve, much improved handling and security. ORM frameworks or OO encapsulation may be too much at this stage.

Comment: I guess i am new to PHP, when i dont have any clue of what bind_param, execute and those commands u use there. And im using mysql not mysqli.

Comment: @user: You should use `mysqli_*`. It's not that hard, with a little reading you will have the basics gathered in less then half an hour. The PHP docs (and this site, too!) are full of ready-to-use, straight-forward examples, and it's not *that* different from `mysql_*`.

Comment: Ok let me try this code, would i need to change all my mysql to mysqli in order to have this code work? Or do PHP accept mysqli and mysql commands combined

Comment: just got 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object, I guess i stick to mysql_ now when I started building everything in mysql(all my other codes)

Comment: @user: I did not say this code runs right-away. You are not connected to a database, so `$mysqli` is not defined yet. Seriously, just open the PHP docs, look at the samples and do a little reading. You have not even *tried* yet, it's a little too early to give up.

Answer (score 3):

How about not repeating yourself:

```
$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE (firstname LIKE '%$firstname%' OR lastname LIKE '%$lastname%')";

if(!empty($sex)){
    $query = $query . " AND sex = '$sex'";
}
```

Comment: How about not building SQL from interpolated strings?

Comment: Could this be SQL injected byron? (mentioned that in your answer)

Comment: this still doesn't solve the fundamental security issues with this code. Not to mention the maintainability issues of rolling your own queries by hand.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT ..."; 

if (!empty($gender))
{
    $sql .= " AND gender = '$gender'";
}
```

And make sure to watch for sql injection.

Comment: You could minimally do something like `$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['gender'])`

Comment: This will "work", and using mysql_real_escape_string() will deal with the security vulnerability (if it's targeting MySql, of course. What about Postgres? MSSql?), but architecturally hand-rolled SQL is a brittle and error-prone approach that is quickly losing favor. In the interest of instilling best practices in the community, we're better off moving people away from these dirty hacks.